# My first simple angular app. Objects aren't displaying

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My first angular homework and I can't get the objects I make in my typescript file to appear when I try to call them into my html page.  I've got to have a little typo somewhere or something, but I've been playing for an hour and I can't find it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

typescript:

```
namespace myApp{
    angular.module("myApp", []);


    class MainController {

        public animal;

        constructor() {

            this.animal = [
                { id: 1, breed: "spaniel", foods: ["alpo", "bones", "cats"] },
                { id: 2, breed: "lab", foods: ["fish", "chicken", "cats"] },]
        }
         }
angular.module("myApp").controller("MainController", MainController);
```

And _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />

    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6">
            <h1>{{animal}}</h1>
            <div>ng-repeat= "food in animal.foods"</div>
            {{foods}}

        </div>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/FrontEnd/JS/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have repeat for animal array also to get the animal object first. Like `<div ng-repeat="an in animal"><div>ng-repeat= "food in an.foods"</div>`

Comment: You are using `ng-controller="MainController as vm`. So you should use  {{vm.animal}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]); // creating new module

    myApp.controller("MainController", function($scope){
        // initializing animals variable
        $scope.animals = [
                { id: 1, breed: "spaniel", foods: ["alpo", "bones", "cats"] },
                { id: 2, breed: "lab", foods: ["fish", "chicken", "cats"] }]; 
    });

</script>
```

And your html should be,

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6">
        <h1>Animals</h1>
        <!-- Loop your animals variable-->
        <div ng-repeat="animal in animals">
            <h1>{{animal.id}}</h1>
            <!-- Loop animal's food-->
            <p ng-repeat="food in animal.foods"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please feel free to ask any doubt in this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.  I see what I was doing wrong in my loops, but I'm afraid that is not the problem.  My problem seems to be more of a setup problem.  My output is:  Animal
ng-repeat= "animal in animals"
animal.id}}.   It just isn't converting

Comment: @ScottVMeyers, Sorry I did't get what you mean? Could you please elaborate the problem?